# Spring Data JPA: PostgreSQL: null collection value inside the IN clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to migrate my DB from MySQL to PostgreSQL. There is no problem with the data, but i've faced with the problem in one Spring Data query which worked fine before (on MySQL). Here is the 'problematic' query (it was simplified for more clear understanding):

```
@Query("SELECT se FROM SomeEntity se " +
       "WHERE coalesce(:someValues, null) is null or se.someColumn in (:someValues))")
List<SomeEntity> findBySearchFilter(Set<SomeEnum> someValues);
```

When `someValues` is not NULL the query works fine, but the problems start when it is NULL:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: <position of the IN clause>
```

Here is the my entity (was simplified as well):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeEntity {

    SomeEnum someColumn;

    @Column(name = "some_column", nullable = false)
    public SomeEnum getSomeColumn() {
        return someColumn;
    }

}
```

And here is the my enum:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
  
  A("A"),
  
  B("B"),
  
  C("C");

  private String value;

  SomeEnum(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }
```

Comment: What are the values in ```:someValues```?

Comment: As i wrote: `the problems start when it is NULL:`. So, it is NULL